# Possible to create 3D multiplayer game server in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js

Is it possible to create a game server with node JS for a 3D windows C++ game?

Is there a way to create the world server of for the game, login, character server is fairly easy to do and is quite possible with node.

But when it comes to the Map server, where it calculates object collision and character positions. How is this properly done? and can it be done with node JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done the same way as any other multiplayer server would be done, simply with different (and maybe more complex) game logics.

You need to implement the 3D physics of the world (that is: object collision logics, character position etc.) both inside the Node.js server and inside the client, and make them communicate via UDP or TCP sockets.

As for the multiplayer communication techniques, I'd recommend you to read this guide: http://gafferongames.com/networking-for-game-programmers/

Regarding physics over network, you should take a look a this, always from the same author: http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/networked-physics/

Comment: The client will be written in C++ no problem. But the server I am thinking of using NodeJS than C++. Thanks for the resources. I will look into it. :)

Comment: But communications of the Map server should be in UDP and TCP or can I use TCP only?

Comment: Generally, UDP is preferred, as far as I know. Luckily, our beloved Glenn Fiedler has a tutorial about UDPvsTCP too: http://gafferongames.com/networking-for-game-programmers/udp-vs-tcp/ That being said, doesn't really matter having client and server in different languages - just use the same encoding (don't know if that's the right word) when sending and receiving game data

Comment: I believe you meant, the same encryption for the packets? :D anyways. thank you. This is great help for resources.

Comment: I did not meant the same encription, but to send game data in a format common both to client and server.